# How can I find a member in a Vector of Struct?

Tags: search, vector, c++17

I have been trying to write a program that finds a takes the maximum value of a 1st-member in a vector of struct, then deletes it along with the value of -1 and +1 from a 2nd-member. But I seem to be running constantly in a runtime error, any idea on where I failed or anything. Still learning vectors.

Here's what I tried to write, with the SOM[] being the array, the value member being the .v and the searched member being .ref :

```
sort(SOM.begin(),SOM.end(),my_cmp);

    int k= SOM.size();
    while(k != 0)
    {
        if(SOM[k-1].v > 0)
        {
            result += SOM[k-1].v;
            int a = SOM[k-1].ref;
            SOM[find_if(SOM.begin(),SOM.end(),[&cm = a](const S& m) -> bool { return (cm-1) == m.ref; }) - SOM.begin()].v = 0;
            SOM[find_if(SOM.begin(),SOM.end(),[&cm = a](const S& m) -> bool { return (cm+1) ==   m.ref; }) - SOM.begin()].v = 0;
            SOM[k-1].v = 0;
        }
        k--;
    }
```

EDIT: I have sorted the vector well using a customized compare function.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question! It is not fully clear, however, what you are trying to do. Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This includes the definition of `SOM` and some example data. P.S. Use a debugger to find out where it crashes. P.P.S. `std::find_if()` can return `SOM.end()` if the element is not found, which means you can do an out-of-bound access. P.P.P.S. Have a look at `std::max_element()`.

Comment: `SOM[some_iter_into_SOM - SOM.begin()].v` is a rather unwieldly way to write `some_iter_into_SOM->v`